# Mongodb aggregates, getting confused with group by

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a collection in mongo that has values like this

```
{ id: Mongo ID,
  Match_Type: Challenge Match,
  Match_Number: 0001
  Challenging_Player: Mark,
  Challenged_Player: John,
}
{ id: Mongo ID,
  Match_Type: Challenge Match,
  Match_Number: 0002
  Challenging_Player: John,
  Challenged_Player: Bob
}
```

The names can appear in either of the 2 columns, either `Challenging Player` or `Challenged Player`. I am trying to do an aggregate to find out the player who has played the maximum number of Challenge matches. Which means I need a group by with Distinct count on both the Challenging and the challenged player.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.getCollection('the_collection').aggregate([
  {$match: { Match_Type: "Challenge Match"}},
  { $project: { players: { $setUnion: [ ["$Challenging_Player"], ["$Challenged_Player"] ] } }},
  { "$unwind" : "$players"},
  {$group : { _id:"$players", count:{$sum:1} } }
  ])
```

Comment: hey ana, thanks it worked like a dream,,But i do have a follow up question. Most of this effort is to of course send data to EJSand then display fields accordingly on the web page. In the same query above i would love to get the total count of the challenge matches as well...how do I incorporate that in the same query. I am able to pull it out differently..can u help please?

Comment: never mind i used $facet and got it done. Thanks Anna.

Answer (score 1):

```
   db.<yourcollection>.aggregate( [
     { $project  : { players: ["$Challenging_Player", "$Challenged_Player"]}},
     { "$unwind" : "$players"},
     { "$group"  : {"_id" : "$players", "count" : {"$sum" : 1}}}
   ] )
```

I am unwinding each of your document into 2 documents one for each player and then group by that field

Comment: hey Kavitha, thanks it worked like a dream,,But i do have a follow up question. Most of this effort is to of course send data to EJSand then display fields accordingly on the web page. In the same query above i would love to get the total count of the challenge matches as well...how do I incorporate that in the same query. I am able to pull it out differently..can u help please?

Comment: never mind i used $facet and got it done. Thanks Kavitha.